# wordpress get_template_directory

Tags: wordpress, directory, themes

I have the following code, what I am expecting it to do is locate the theme I am using and place that path before the /images/bg.png so far I just get the location which is localhost/nameoffolder/images/bg.png but what i want is localhost/nameoffolder/wp-content/themes/images/bg.png

```
<img src="<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/images/bg.png"></img>
```

this is the directory I would like to display
http://localhost:8888/fiftyfity/wp-content/themes/fiftyfity/images/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used this code instead and it worked

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/images/bg.png"></img>
```

Answer (score 7):

get_template_directory() returns the directory, but it doesn't echo it.. so if you use it with echo it will work

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/images/bg.png"></img>
```

but I will suggest to use get_template_directory_uri() instead, because above will not be portable ( windows use backward slashes as separator )

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/bg.png"></img>
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I wanted to say this worked for me; this is the difference between C:/xampp/blahblahblah and http://localhost/blahblahblah - I'm working with a Wordpress theme in localhost and the get_template_directory() wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

that's odd... Can you try get_stylesheet_directory() instead and see what that returns?