# Image not loading even though path is correct

Tags: php, html, wordpress

The file path is:

```
theme 
   assets
      src
         images
            grey-arrow.svg
```

**Markup**:

```
<?php $getIcon = get_template_directory().'/assets/src/images/grey-arrow.svg';?>

<div><img src="<?php echo $getIcon; ?>"/></div>

<?php echo $getIcon;?>
```

The image doesn't load and an echo of `$getIcon` returns:

```
/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/theme/assets/src/images/grey-arrow.svg
```

... Which is the correct path. Ideas on why the image doesn't load?

Comment: Try using get_template_directory_uri() instead

Comment: Could you please use  get_template_directory_uri() instead of get_template_directory()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wordpress get\_template\_directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349249/wordpress-get-template-directory)

Answer (score 0):

You should echo it and also you are closing your php tag properly.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/src/images/grey-arrow.svg"/>
```

or you can use bloginfo which is easier to remember and use (You need not echo)

```
 <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/src/images/grey-arrow.svg"/>
```